# 2 methods are called from two different threads at the same time - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

If these methods are called from two different threads at the same time, what will be the result?

```
public class FirstWord {
       public static synchronized void writeFirstWord(boolean fromSecondWord) throws Exception {
              if(fromSecondWord == false)
                     SecondWord.writeSecondWord();
              System.out.print("Redflex"); }}

public class SecondWord {
       public static synchronized void writeSecondWord() throws Exception {
              Thread.sleep(100);
              FirstWord.writeFirstWord(true);  
              System.out.print(" Traffic Systems"); }}
```

Comment: why cant you execute and see it!

Comment: Homework assignment much?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: executed? got any error? tell us what happened?

Comment: @Vicheanak It depends on which is called first, and if `writeFirstWord` is called first, whether the parameter is true or false...

Comment: if both are called at the same time, mutual block. Both Threads get the corresponding lock, and when they try to get the other lock, they have to wait... forever.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock is very likely in the code sample you have - if you have 2 threads, say ThreadA and ThreadB, then given this scenario:

ThreadA calls `FirstWord.writeFirstWord(false)` and the thread pauses once inside
ThreadB calls `SecondWord.writeSecondWord()` and the thread pauses once inside

Now ThreadA continues it'll stop at `SecondWord.writeSecondWord();` as ThreadB has the lock SecondWord.

ThreadB can't continue because ThreadA has the lock on FirstWord.

The result is a deadlock.

Note that this isn't the only possible outcome of this code - depending on timing etc the code *may* run just fine for a while, but its very likely that you'll hit a deadlock at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The result is unpredictable due to the unpredictable nature of `sleep()`.

Also, it depends on how many cores there are, and what parameter you provide in the `writeFirstWord(boolean)` call.

I'll leave it to you to figure out the details :-)

---

Hint: one possibility is deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Example SSCCE (modified):

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FirstWord.writeFirstWord(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SecondWord.writeSecondWord(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

}

class FirstWord {
    public static synchronized void writeFirstWord(boolean fromSecondWord) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("FirstWord start");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        if (!fromSecondWord) SecondWord.writeSecondWord(true);
        System.out.println("FirstWord end");
    }
}

class SecondWord {
    public static synchronized void writeSecondWord(boolean fromFirstWord) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SecondWord start");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        if (!fromFirstWord) FirstWord.writeFirstWord(true);  
        System.out.println("SecondWord end");
    }
}
```

As you can see the console shows:

```
FirstWord start
SecondWord start
```

The first thread "enters" into the `FirstWord` synchronized block while the second one enters the `SecondWord` one. Then, after sleeping a little bit, the first thread tries to enter into the SecondWord method, and has to wait because the second thread has the lock for that method.

While this happens, the second thread is also waiting to get the other lock, and that's why **both threads block** and never reach the "end", as **they never get both locks**.

If you remove `Thread.sleep` in both methods it may work. As said, it is unpredictable. You can't know which thread is going to enter first.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.blt;

    public class ThreadsExample implements Runnable { 
       public static void main(String args[]) {     
        Thread t=new Thread(new ThreadsExample());
        Thread t1=new Thread(new ThreadsExample());     
        t.start();
        t1.start();      
}

    public void run()  {    
    try { 
        writeSecondWord();  
    }   
    catch(Exception e)  {   
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }
 }

    public static synchronized void writeSecondWord() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        writeFirstWord(true);  
        System.out.print(" Traffic Systems"); 
        } 

    public static synchronized void writeFirstWord(boolean fromSecondWord) throws Exception {
        if(fromSecondWord == false)
               writeSecondWord();
        System.out.print("Redflex"); 
     }
 }
```

Output is: Redflex Traffic SystemsRedflex Traffic Systems

Running is above code is fine but there are fair chances that code will produce deadlock at some point of time.